# Can I prepare baby cereal in advance?

Tags: food, travel

I'm preparing for a long airplane flight with my family. I've been filling and freezing some refillable baby food pouches with chicken/veggie soup, etc. I'd like to also bring a couple of pouches with a baby cereal (probably oatmeal) + water + applesauce combination so that I have an easy ready breakfast-on-the-go. Is it ok to prepare this the night before the flight and put the pouch in the fridge?

Comment: Since your primary concern is about food preparation, storage, and safety issues, the folks on our [Cooking site](http://cooking.stackexchange.com) are extremely knowledgeable about these issues.

Answer (score 3):

I never had any success pre-mixing cereal for my kids. They usually *hated* the consistency when it was anything other than fresh. Honestly, if you are just using water and applesauce, it seems like just bringing the dry cereal + a pouch of applesauce+ a bottle of water and mixing it in an empty cup (which you should have no trouble procuring on the plane) isn't such a hassle. I used to do this in the car, at restaurants, at relatives houses, the park...it's worth a *little* extra effort to avoid having cereal spit back in your face (or another passenger's!)

If you are asking because you want to use the pouches (I don't blame you! Mess free!) for feeding convenience, I would at least suggest warming the mixture a bit; this seems to help the texture. You could ask the flight attendant for warm water in a cup and just float the pouch for a minute and then give it a few squeezes to break up the lumps.

I wish you the best luck attempting a long flight with a young child. You are braver than me!

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I should try it in advance to see if they'll take it. I'm assuming that food-safety-wise it's ok? (And it's 3 of them actually :) I'm somewhat terrified)

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be safe as long as you keep it refrigerated and then serve it quickly after reheating.  I'm assuming you are packing a cooler or bringing along an ice pack at the very least?